# Given an input and a program when can you derive the output faster than just running the program?

Tags: halting-problem

Given an input string W, a description of a turning machine M, and a target output string O (W,M,O) as input, when can a machine M' decide, in fewer steps than simply running M on W, if running M on W, in fact, produces O or not?

What are the circumstances under which this faster M' exists and when is this impossible, i.e. when does this problem reduce to the halting problem (seems like it does)?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to formalize your question. What is a program in this context? A Turing machine? What do you consider "running the program"? The answer might change depending on how you define that.

Comment: Yes a program meaning a Turing machine. And running the program means feeding it to the machine.

Comment: I'm sorry to be pedantic but "feeding it to the machine" is still vague. Do you consider "running the program" if I simulate the input Turing machine $T$ in another Turing machine $M$? Do you consider it running the program if I simulate a different Turing machine $T'$ (chosen as a function of $T$) in another Turing machine $M$?

Comment: @Steven is this formal enough? Sorry for lack of clarity. I think it's now a reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
for i from 1 to 10000000000
  do nothing
end for
output 1
```

In general, however, you can't save much. Indeed, the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) states, roughly speaking, that you cannot simulate a $T(n)$-time Turing machine running in time $o(T(n)/\log T(n))$.

Comment: good example--but I'm looking for a general statement about when its possible to deduce the output without running (or in fewer steps) and when its not. Thanks!

Comment: The time hierarchy theorem shows that in general you cannot gain much. I suggest looking it up.

Comment: I've heard the soundbite that, in general, you can't predict what a program is going to do without running it. But I couldn't find a reference to a theorem that explicitly says that. Ive heard of time higherarchy and I can see how via diagnolization there would be some programs that couldn't be computed in less time. I guess its the same question. Sick thanks.

Comment: @RingRing "what a program is going to do" is too vague to appear in a rigorous statement. The nearest to what you might have heard, I believe, is [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), which states that all non-trivial, semantic properties of programs are undecidable. "non-trivial semantic property" corresponds to "do something" by a program.

Comment: @RingRing, "Sick thanks"? Typo?

Comment: @JohnL. It’s slang.

Answer (score 1):

In general, what you ask is impossible (regardless of the number of steps that $M'$ takes). If such a machine $M'$ existed then you could solve the halting problem.

Let $T$ and $x$ be a Turing machine and an input string, respectively. Consider a Turing Machine $T'$ that first simulates $T$ on $x$ and, when (if) $T$ terminates, clears the tape and halts.

Now running $M'$ with input $(T', \epsilon, \epsilon)$ decides whether $T'$ outputs the empty string. But this happens if and only if $T'$ terminates.

Comment: trying to combine your guys answers--yours says no because of halting problem (regardless of number of steps) and Yuval's says no because of time higherarchy theorem. Both are no's but for diff reasons.